# Autonomous Lawn edger + OpenCV guidance

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

Hello im working on a autonomous lawn edger for a project. The goal of it is to edge three sides of a rectangular patio. The edger will purely ride on the concrete and hang the blade over the edge to cut it. My part it to create the guidance system and we have decided to use computer vision. Specifically OpenCV on an Raspberry Pi 4. So far I have working code that takes in images of a grass/sidewalk edge and displays a line on it for the robot to follow, this being done via the slope of the line. My issue is 90 degree turns (right turns only). I'm not sure how to get it to a point where it initiates a right turn when close to the edge. I've looked into Hough Lines but am not sure how to extract data from that. I will provided the working code below if any one wants to see that. Does any one have any ideas how to complete the said turn? I appreciate any help and this is my first time posting.
Here is a picture example of the corners

[Sidewalk/grass corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUIV8.jpg)

'''

```
def angleOfLine(filename,showpics=False,save=False):
    startTime=time.time()       #get start time to see how long program takes to run
    pic=cv.imread(filename)     #set picture location/name to process
    h,w,c=pic.shape             #Gets picture dimensions
    if h>w:                     #Checks if taller then wider
        temp=w
        w=h
        h=temp
    
    blur = cv.blur(pic,(5,5))                   #blur image with 5x5 filter
    blur0=cv.medianBlur(blur,5)                 #take out blips with median filter
    blur1= cv.GaussianBlur(blur0,(5,5),0)       #blur 
    blur2= cv.bilateralFilter(blur1,9,75,75)    #blends pic into background
    
    
    hsv = cv.cvtColor(blur2, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)  #change to hsv color space
    low_val = np.array([36, 36, 43])            #Picks out lower color range
    high_val = np.array([199, 202, 203])        #Picks out upper color range
    mask = cv.inRange(hsv, low_val, high_val)   #create a mask with that range
       
    #sizes
    size1=100 #Rectangular structural element 
    linex=100 #Line struc element
    liney=h
        
    #Make structural elements      
    se1=cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(size1,size1))       #rectangle   
    line=cv.getStructuringElement(cv.MORPH_RECT,(linex,liney))      #line

    #Morphology   
    closed=cv.dilate(mask,se1,iterations = 1)   #dilate mask
    opened=cv.erode(closed,line,iterations = 1) #erode image
    
    #shows originaloverlayed with cutout
    res = cv.bitwise_and(pic,pic, mask= opened) #puts mask over original pic
    
    #Edge Detection
    edges = cv.Canny(opened, 100, 200) # Canny Edge Detection
    
    #Rotated Image 180 deg
    rotated=cv.rotate(edges, cv.ROTATE_180) #spin image since counting top left
    
    #Set some vars and arrays
    count=0
    xdata=[]
    ydata=[]
    
    #loop through image and find edge line points
    for a in range(h):
        for b in range(w):
            if rotated[b,a] == 255:
                xdata.append(a)
                ydata.append(b)
            count+=1
    
    #transpose a data set
    x=np.reshape(xdata,(-1,1))
    y=ydata
    
    #Gets angle of line
    model=LinearRegression().fit(x, y)
    slope=model.coef_
    angle=np.rad2deg(np.arctan(slope))
    """
    lines = cv.HoughLines(edges, 1, np.pi / 2, 150, None, 0, 0)
    cdst = cv.cvtColor(edges, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)

    if lines is not None:
        for i in range(0, len(lines)):
            rho = lines[i][0][0]
            theta = lines[i][0][1]
            a = math.cos(theta)
            b = math.sin(theta)
            x0 = a * rho
            y0 = b * rho
            pt1 = (int(x0 + 1000*(-b)), int(y0 + 1000*(a)))
            pt2 = (int(x0 - 1000*(-b)), int(y0 - 1000*(a)))
            cv.line(cdst, pt1, pt2, (0,0,255), 3, cv.LINE_AA)
     
      """      
    #shows the progress of picture processing 
    if showpics==True:
        #Show Pics
        cv.imshow('',pic)
        cv.waitKey()
        cv.imshow('',mask)
        cv.waitKey()
        cv.imshow('',closed)
        cv.waitKey()
        cv.imshow('',edges)
        cv.waitKey()
        cv.imshow('',res)
        cv.waitKey()
        
        #cv.imshow('',cdst)
        #cv.waitKey()
    #Write pictures to save
    if save==True:
        cv.imwrite('mask5.jpg',mask)
        cv.imwrite('closed5.jpg',closed)
        cv.imwrite('edges5.jpg',edges)
        cv.imwrite('res5.jpg',res)

    #close all windows
   
    cv.destroyAllWindows()
    
    #gets angle 
    if abs(angle) >90:
        angle=180-abs(angle)
    else :angle=90-abs(angle)
    
    #gets sign of angle
    if -slope<0:
        sign=-1
    else: sign=1
    
    angle=angle*sign
    print("The angle of the edge in", filename, " is", truncate(angle,3) )
    print("The size of the image is ",h,"x",w)
    print("The process took",truncate(time.time()-startTime,3),"s")
    print()
```

'''

Comment: pictures please. perhaps review [mre]. and may I recommend to drop code comments that are obvious? comments are supposed to explain things that aren't obvious. not every line needs to have a comment. you might like https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz ive add a sample image. I have no actual one right now since there is snow everywhere but this is the idea. The comments are for my group since they are all Mechanical engineers and dont know CV

Comment: `dilate(mask) # dilate mask` only makes sense if these people ignore the code entirely and don't see anything but the comment. oh well. I'm not gonna argue. -- as for the picture... how do you expect to do image processing if you don't have images? that's a sketch and I was hoping to see a LOT more information than that. -- btw, you have a bug in your indexing. indexing is [i,j] or equivalently [y,x]

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz you make a good point about the dilate comments ill look into that. I meant i dont have images of the specific setup that I will be facing. What i showed is an example and im looking for methods in order to know when to turn. The robot will face a situation like this so that is why i provided that since i have no actual pictures at the moment. An idea someone suggested today is to check area of pixels in the image that are “cement” vs grass to know when its going to turn. Im not sure what the bug is doing since i get the results im looking for.

Comment: you can't possibly work on this problem without data. even if you don't have a lawn mower yet, you need a camera and you need to use it like it's intended to be used in this situation. if you don't have a plan for _**how** to use the camera_ yet, you should discard all that code and look for an open discussion.